# Setting overflow on container breaks translateZ

Tags: css, google-chrome, overflow, microsoft-edge, css-transforms

I want a cool scrolling effect on my website like this:

[image]

There are two background images that scroll much slower than the rest of the page, divided by another element with a higher `z-index` value and unmodified scroll speed.

I have managed to do so in Firefox using 3d transform and overflow: hidden (as you can see, the two background images do not overlap). Here's the significant part of the code:

#### HTML:

```html
<div class="container-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="slow-scroll">
            <img src="...">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```css
.container-container {
    perspective: 100px;
}
.container {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slow-scroll {
    transform: translateZ(-900px) scale(10.5);
}
```

My intention was to do the same as in the GIF - have a container with regular scroll speed that would contain the slower scrolling background, so that the overflow could be hidden, thus making it impossible for the two background images to overlap.

However, this doesn't work for Chrome or Microsoft Edge - the background images act as if the `translateZ()` value was absent (the `scale` still works normally though). This happens if I set `overflow: hidden` to any value except `initial`, `revert`, or `unset`.

Can this be fixed? Is there a workaround?

Note: I have looked around and saw [this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOLpK.gif), but it's outdated and the accepted answer does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, and the sample images provided, I think what you're looking for is a parallax scrolling effect. Simply refer to this tutorial below, which contains a simple example. I think it will help you.

[**How TO - Parallax Scrolling**](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp)

**Edit**:

And according to your description, you mentioned that translateZ() not work in Edge, I created a simple demo and tested it, and I found it works normally in Edge(version 97.0.1072.55). I think maybe there is some problem with the code, such as this line:

```
transform: transform: translateZ(-900px) scale(10.5);
```

And if you want to implement this requirement, you could try to create multiple layers and set different translateZ() values for them. Simply refer to this example: [Pure CSS Parallax Websites - Demo3](https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/demo3)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however, I am looking for a solution that enables the background to be also scrollable, but with lower speed, which is not possible using the link you provided

Comment: Hi @Quijibo, I've edited my answer, I think it might help you.

Comment: The `transform: transform: ...` was just me accidentally typing an extra word in, sorry. I appreciate your answer, but I am specifially asking about 3d transforms in combination with the `overflow` property. The 3d effect works fine without it and I know how to make a 3d CSS effect, but I don't know how to use it in combination with `overflow: hidden`.